# Adding colour by group to ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, sentiment-analysis

I have analysed text, and am trying to visualise the frequency of words in three groups. I want to set the three groups a colour each, so all my graphs with the groups are easily comparable. Below is the structure of my data and the code I'm using to make the graph. I'm not sure how to assign each group its own colour and reproduce this in my script. At the moment it just gives produces varying shades of blue depending on the group.

Thanks

```
structure(list(group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), word = c("happy", "dance", "pain", "pen", 
"feel", "head", "football", "year", "asthma", "contagious", "flowers", 
"lamp", "calendar", "phone", "cereal", "book", "acne", "low", 
"pain"), n = c(134, 138, 157, 195, 209, 213, 266, 414, 114, 114, 
126, 149, 182, 193, 205, 223, 103, 110, 118), row = c(1, 2, 3, 
4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19)), row.names = c(NA, 
-19L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

and the code for the graph

```
# Colours for the three groups
my_colors <- c("#FFDBCE", "#8CAEAE", "#beb6d7")


#Organise words by group 
wordsbygroup <- script %>% 
  group_by(group) %>%
  count(word, group, sort = TRUE) %>%
  slice(seq_len(8)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(group,n) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) 

#Visualise words by group 

wordsbygroup %>%
  ggplot(aes(row, n, fill = group)) +
  geom_col(show.legend = F) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = "Word Count") +
  ggtitle("Frequent Words by group") + 
  facet_wrap(~group, scales = "free_y","fixed_x") +
  scale_x_continuous(  # This handles replacement of row 
    breaks = wordsbygroup$row, # notice need to reuse data frame
    labels = wordsbygroup$word) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image: graph output]

Comment: Can you add the output plot too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I turned your fill group into a factor to make the group discrete.

Then added `scale_fill_manual(values = my_colors)` to assign the fill colors.

```
wordsbygroup %>%
  ggplot(aes(row, n, fill = as.factor(group))) +
  geom_col(show.legend = F) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = "Word Count") +
  ggtitle("Frequent Words by group") + 
  facet_wrap(~group, scales = "free_y","fixed_x") +
  scale_x_continuous(  # This handles replacement of row 
    breaks = wordsbygroup$row, # notice need to reuse data frame
    labels = wordsbygroup$word) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = my_colors) + 
  coord_flip()
```

[image]